# Why my dell vostro 1015 runs slowly?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, performance

I have a Dell Vostro 1015 which has an intel T5670 CPU, 4GB ram, 120GB SSD hard drive, The problem is that I am not satisfied with the performance considering the other notebook I have. It is a Lenovo 3000 n100 which has an intel t5500 CPU, 3GB ram, 120GB SSD. Dell has a GM45 chipset and Lenovo has a 945GM chipset which is older and has lower performance than GM45. I am just using WinRAR(benchmark tool in the tools menu) to compare two computers. While Lenovo gets a score between 1200-1300, dell can get only a score between 650-750. Performance differences easily can be reviewed while using two computers. I installed fresh windows 7 32 bit on both notebooks. I updated all the drivers and bios.  I also run windows 10 on dell before. Its performance was worse than windows 7. I tested all the hardware with the diagnosis program which is can be used in the booting menu. There wasn't any problem. I changed the CPU with Intel p8400 and got a score between 550-650 which is lower than intel T5670 has. I exchanged the rams between Lenovo and dell but dell still had worse performance. I tested both SSD drives with a crystal disk mark. Lenovo had a reading score of around 130 but dell got a reading score over 200. How could it be worse than Lenovo although it has a better CPU, chipset, SSD, ram? Do you have any recommendations to try ?

Comment: You could use something like HWinfo to compare the processor speeds, the memory speeds, and check that the processor in the Dell is not getting too hot.

Comment: Is it having network problems that are slowing down the system.  Check your performance monitors when running your benchmarks.  Is there a lot of network activity?  Is it suffering from an ET phone home problem?

Comment: Thank you for the comments. By using the Hwinfo I have detected the problem. The reason is that bios doesn't accept charger for the full functionality. It fixes the CPU at 940 MHz. My solution is that using Throttlestop to be able to increase CPU speed.